# How do I write a split statement in SQL, that divides a record into 2 records if months are different for start and end dates?

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, netezza

I have the following SQL code, and I need to break a row into two rows if the 'COV_PRD_STRT_DT' and 'COV_PRD_END_DT' are different months .

```
WITH CTE AS
( SELECT COV_PRD_STRT_DT,TO_DATE,COV_PRD_END_DT as MO_END_DT, 
  case when dateadd (DAY,-DAY(DATEADD(MONTH,1, BF.COV_PRD_STRT_DT)),
  DATEADD(MONTH,1, d.from_date)) 
    < To_date THEN DATEADD(DAY,-DAY(DATEADD(MONTH,1, BF.COV_PRD_END_DT)),
    DATEADD(MONTH,1, BF.COV_PRD_END_DT)) 
    ELSE To_Date END as MO_END_DT          
  FROM BILLING_FACT
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT COV_PRD_STRT_DT,To_date,DATEADD(DAY,1,BF.COV_PRD_END_DT) as                                                                          MO_END_DT, < TO_DATE  
   THEN DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEADD(DAY,1,BF.COV_PRD_END_DT)))
   ELSE To_Date END as MO_END_DT
   FROM CTE WHERE COV_PRD_END_DT < To_Date
 ) 

select * from CTE order by COV_PRD_STRT_DT,COV_PRD_END_DT
```

thanks

Comment: can you show some sample data and expected result?

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar - hi, unfortunately i  cannot supply sample data bec it's PHI

Comment: can be some made up sample but of same data types

Comment: I can't send you sample data but can explain the scenario I'm working with ,My source has 2 columns with start dt and end dt . and amounts . If the  end date has a different month from the start, we want to split that row into two rows -

Comment: - one row  with the start date being from start date to end that of the month (of the start date) ; and then the other row being from the beginning of second month to  end of the 2nd month

Comment: just the date? how about the amounts, is that going to be split as well?

Comment: If  you want an answer you really should consider cooking up sample data for us. It doesn't matter that your data is PHI, just think of an example. Anyway... what happens if it crosses three months or four months? The way to do this is to join to a a tally or calendar table

Answer (score 0):

If start date and end date is not equal on month level, use cov_prd_strt_dt as start date and get its month end date as end date and have the month start date of cov_prd_end_dt as the other row's start date and cov_prd_end_dt as end date to split the dates

```
SELECT cov_prd_strt_dt strt_dt,
       CASE WHEN DATE_PART('Month', cov_prd_strt_dt) <> DATE_PART('Month', cov_prd_end_dt)
            THEN LAST_DAY(cov_prd_strt_dt)
            ELSE cov_prd_end_dt
        END end_dt
  FROM billing_fact
 UNION
SELECT CASE WHEN DATE_PART('Month', cov_prd_strt_dt) <> DATE_PART('Month', cov_prd_end_dt)
            THEN DATE_TRUNC(cov_prd_end_dt)
            ELSE cov_prd_strt_dt
        END strt_dt,
        cov_prd_end_dt end_dt,
  FROM billing_fact
```

Using UNION only will eliminate duplicate records for those that were not processed for split (same month for cov_prd_strt_dt and cov_prd_end_dt).

Comment: above query is not working throws me error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ^ found "FROM" (at char 387) expecting an identifier found a keyword

Comment: I am working on Netezza database. Netezza does not support DATE_TRUNC logic I guess

Comment: sorry, there was an extra comma on the second query before FROM

Answer (score 0):

Nice answers for one or two resulting rows. The general case, a join will do a better job, in performance/relational thinking as well as code readability (I know the last point can be a matter of opinion, but never the less it is important)

First I create a temp table with all the relevant months (but I guess you ought to have a similar table yourself already):

```
Create temp table months as 
Select distinct substr(cov_prd_strt_dt,1,7) yyyy_mm
Union
Select distinct substr(cov_prd_end_dt,1,7) yyyy_mm
```

Then to the actual join:

```
Select 
    *, 
    substr(cov_prd_start_dt,1,7) start_yyyy_mm, 
    substr(cov_prd_end_dt,1,7) end_yyyy_mm
From billing_fact f
Join months m
    On m.yyyy_mm between f.start_yyyy_mm and f.end_yyyy_mm
```

I hope this helps